# Webhooks to fetch data from shopify to crm

Tags: shopify, integration, webhooks, crm

I need to know if we need separate webhooks for lead capture and event capture for Shopify if I want to integrate my CRM with Shopify using webhooks.

Also, will different events like cart creation, order creation, and refund creation require different webhooks or a single webhook works for capturing all events?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find the list of all the webhook topics as per 2022-10 API: https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2022-04/resources/webhook#top

Here the ones that you might find useful:

- orders/cancelled, orders/create, orders/fulfilled, orders/paid, orders/partially_fulfilled, orders/updated
- refunds/create
- carts/create, carts/update
- checkouts/create, checkouts/update
- customers/create, customers/disable, customers/enable, customers/update, customers_marketing_consent/update

Each of these is a different webhook, I'm not sure what do you mean by "event creation".